# How to customize extjs size of actionSheet and actionSheet's buttons?

Tags: javascript, extjs, web-applications, extjs4, sencha-touch

So how I can  customize buttons of actionSheet? Cls config doesn't work. I can change style of buttons only by  ui config...

And how i can change size of actionSheet panel and size of actionSheet panel's element, for example: fields, buttons etc. Cause: a actionSheet looks great on dekstop, but so small on mobile.

Gracio!

Answer (score 1):

ExtJS has a specific config to adjust the size of the buttons:

[scale](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.button.Button-cfg-scale) : "small"/"medium"/"large"
The size of the Button. Three values are allowed:

- `'small'` - Results in the button element being 16px high.
- `'medium'`- Results in the button element being 24px high.
- `'large'` - Results in the button element being 32px high.

Default value is: 'small'

**This is in version 4**

However in the Modern toolkit version, you will have to adjust the size via properties of CSS classes.

- [cls](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/modern/Ext.Button.html#cfg-cls)
- [instanceCls](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/modern/Ext.Button.html#cfg-instanceCls)
- [userCls](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/modern/Ext.Button.html#cfg-userCls)